# Symfony2 can't find registry service in controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have a basic controller in which I want to use the entity manager :

```
<?php

namespace HanziGame\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use HanziGame\MainBundle\Entity\Hanzi;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {       
    $em = $this->get('registry')->getEntityManager();

    return $this->render('HanziGameMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "registry".
500 Internal Server Error - NonExistentServiceException
```

It seems to me I am following the Symfony book (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine/orm.html), I don't see how to correct the issue. 
What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing

```
$em = $this->get('registry')->getEntityManager();
```

To

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
```

Worked for me based on this version of Symfony2:

http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.0.0BETA1.tgz

Answer (score 3):

Registry service introduced in beta2, wich now in master branch.

Comment: Thanks! Slightly annoying that the downloadable zip doesn't have it, but I guess it's to be expected.